# Completing the Star Player challenge

Tags: achievements, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I've had a few matches recently (Sabotage) recently where I ended with a greater than 5:1 Kill/Death ratio. The Star Player challenge is unlocked, but neither match completed it.

The actual numbers were 2:0 in the first match (didn't get Flawless, I'm assuming because the game was too quick) and 1:0 in the second match (got Flawless - game was longer than the first but still pretty quick).

Is there minimum threshold of time and/or number of kills that you need to actually complete the challenge? Is it limited to specific game types? The text itself simply says 5:1 and doesn't specify any minimums or other restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just completed this challenge by finishing a short game (no more than 2-3 minutes) with 5 kills and 0 deaths. It looks like time is not a factor, and there is a requirement of 5+ kills.

Comment: Yes, as the challenge says : "Star Player : Finish a game with a **kill / death ratio** of 5:1", meaning you k/d ratio must be over 5 at the end of the game (no matter how long it is, wether you win or not, …).

Comment: Right, but I had accomplished that in two games previously without completing the challenge (2-0 and 1-0). It appears to require a minimum of 5 kills, which is not clearly stated.

Comment: Well, how 2-0 and 1-0 is a 5 k/d ratio ? lol, you calculate your k/d ratio for a game by dividing your number of kills by your number of deaths you had in the game !

Comment: Right, but zero is an edge case because you can't divide by zero. In all cases except 0 deaths, having greater than a 5:1 kdr means having at least 5 times as many kills as deaths. 2-0 and 1-0 satisfy that (5*0=0). It's a wierd edge case, which is why I asked (since I couldn't be sure it was minimum 5 kills or if the previous games were just too short to matter.

Comment: Well, if you're on COD Elite, and you get a flawless game, when you go to your recent games, your k/d for this game is your number of kills during it. Regarding the length of the game, if there was a limit, it would be in the description :)

Comment: Cool, didn't know COD Elite did that. However, there is no time restriction mentioned in the Flawless description, though there appears to be one (I didn't get it for my short 2-0 game, despite playing the entire game)

Comment: Are you sure about that ? That's strange.. On http://callofduty.wikia.com, they give the list of the challenges and tips on how to complete them, and for this one they suggest "Find a corner of the map where nobody goes, and stay there the whole game"..

Comment: Stupid comment, you were not talking about number of kills but game duration..

Comment: I just saw a discussion on a forum, saying that for the flawless challenge, you ay need 10+ kills. Would be too easy otherwise..

Comment: That's clearly not accurate - I got it with only 1 kill (game was a Sabotage match that ended really quickly)

Comment: Well I don't know how you got it with 1:0 and not 2:0 then, lol..

Comment: The 2:0 game was even shorter than the 1:0 game, which leads me to believe there is a minimum time required